# Accessing UIbutton in Xcode 12.4 from Visual Studio for Mac using Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, xamarin

I'm trying to get myself a little bit into iOS-Programming. As I'd like to use C#.Net for coding of the apps logic, I'm following along the introduction from the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/hello-ios/hello-ios-quickstart?pivots=macos

Now in step15 it describes how to "... change the Name property in the Identity section of the Properties Pad to XXX ...", but I cannot find this property in my Xcode 12.4. I assume, that Microsofts documentation is taken from the latest Xcode 13.x, and this property is not available in Xcode 12.4. Am I right?

Can anyone assist me in how to set this property in Xcode 12.4 and therefore make this button available to my C#-Class in Visual Studio (this would be step20 in description above)?

Hint: I cannot upgrade to Xcode 13.x, as I'm still running Catalina-MacOS (my MacBook is to old to upgrade). Xcode 12.4 is the latest version available for Catalina-MacOS.

Thanks very much for your assistance
Kind regards,
Ralf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer/solution in another Microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/ios-ui/creating-ui-objects?tabs=macos

Quote:
"When you design your UI with Interface Builder you must **create an Outlet for each control** that you wish to reference in C#. This is done by ..."